# Azure Table Storage Doesn't Save Everything in Entity definition

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

This is the same of the entity that I am planning to save in the Azure Table Storage (ATS):

```
public class CarEntity : TableEntity
{

    public CarEntity(string objPartitionKey, string objRowKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = objPartitionKey;
        this.RowKey = objRowKey;
    }

    public string TableName
    {
        get { return "EntityTableName"; }
    }

    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    // and this goes on
    public string Property60 { get; set; }
}
```

Not all properties are required. Population of records depend on the selections that the user would be saving (e.g this is a CarEntity - if the user ordered wheels, properties WheelSize and WheelQuantity would be populated, if the user asks for repainting, RepaintingColor would be populated and so, on).

Assuming that there are 60 properties in this entity, not all properties gets saved in ATS. Despite a property being defined and no error being returned, that data doesn't get saved in the table. I know that there's a limit of 1MB per entity but considering the computations that we have done, it is kinda far from the 1MB limit.

Any help why columns don't appear even if the properties are saved accordingly? My save function is defined as follows:

```
    public static CarEntity CarInsertOrReplace(CarEntity entity)        
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        var table = SetupTable(entity.TableName);
        table.CreateIfNotExists();

        TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrReplace(entity);

        TableResult result = table.Execute(insertOrMergeOperation);
        CarEntity objEntity = result.Result as CarEntity;
        return objEntity;
    }
```

Comment: I think my problem was answered by this - [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071899/storing-decimal-data-type-in-azure-tables[/link]. I just didn't realize that decimal datatype would give me issues on this. Thanks to those who help!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the properties for your Entity vary based on the usage. What's probably happening is that Azure Table Storage is only creating columns for properties that are not null (have a value set). So you are will only see columns created for properties that have been set.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if Table Storage is performing as you require but not necessarily as you expect. As answered by @Paul Fryer ATS will not store null values and as you do not (going by your quoted code) initialise the CarEntity properties they will be null by default. Therefore only properties set by the user will be saved to the table.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452242.aspx #Remarks:

> If the Insert Or Replace Entity operation is used to replace an
>   entity, any properties from the previous entity will be removed if the
>   new entity does not define them. Properties with a null value will
>   also be removed.

Also, from your code

```
TableResult result = table.Execute(insertOrMergeOperation);
CarEntity objEntity = result.Result as CarEntity;
```

result will contain the TableOperation not a copy of the full entity in case that was what you were expecting.

This scenario might be the difference between using, for example, a SQL table where fields that are not given a value have a database default or default to null, against the Azure table model where fields not given a value do not exist. You just need to be aware of that difference when reading/writing to the storage chosen.

If you require all fields to be persisted to the table then provide a default value for each property, e.g. string.Empty

Answer (score 0):

If strings are null or empty then it doesn't save the property at all. You're not doing anything wrong, you just have to consider this in your design when you're working with them.

If you're using TableEntity then it does the null/empty check for you.  If you're using DynamicTableEntity then you have to do the check yourself.